# 404 The requested resource is not available on deployed war

Tags: apache, web-applications, war

I deployed a web application on a remote apache server but when trying to access the site, I got the 404 error. I checked the logs and could only find the following error but not sure if this is related:

```
Jan 11, 2016 5:06:51 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.
WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-7/webapps/user-token-api/WEB-INF/lib/
tomcat-embed-el-8.0.28.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 
9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Jan 11, 2016 5:06:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext 
startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 11, 2016 5:06:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/user-token-api] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Do I actually  need to include that jar in the lib folder or is this some other issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to have that class/jar in your application's WEB-INF/lib directory.  Tomcat already packages the EL API and implementation files as part of its product.  The EL API is in the /lib/el-api.jar and the impl is in the /lib/jasper-el.jar file.

I'm not exactly sure of the specific reason for your error reported but my guess is that it could be a classloading issue.

Hope this helps.